# How to manipulate MySQL DB on a OpenWRT router from a Net client

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, shell, openwrt

I run OPENWRT on a router, which is set up as an access point (AP). My goal is to implement a dynamic rule set  for the clients that are connected to this AP, e.g. IP block, Ad block, etc . I think with the help of certain OpenWRT pakages e.g.  "IPtables", "DNSmasq" that should be possbile and not to complicated. My approach is the following:

1.) Create a  database with MYSQL on the AP to capture IP Adresses and indivual rulesets (e.g. adblock ON/OFF) for the IPs.

2.) Use Shellscripts on the AP to implement the rules.

3.) To make it more userfriendly I want to use a Internet Browser on one of the clients to connect to the OpenWRT Router and use a GUI in order to manipulate the Database and execute the Shellsripts.

My question is related to Step 3 : I am not sure how to set this up. I think I cannot use PHP (server based) since I cannot install a Webserver on the router (memory limit) Would javascript work?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> I think I cannot use PHP (server based) since I cannot install a Webserver on the router (memory limit)

This statement gives me significant cause to doubt your ability to complete the task you've set yourself.

1) No, javascript *in your browser* has no capability to connect to a MySQL database

2) Running javascript serverside (i.e. on the WRT device) e.g. using node.js will have similar overheads to a PHP solution

What is preventing you from running a webserver elsewhere then triggering the required actions via the current control channel (i.e. ssh) Indeed, why does the MySQL server need to reside on the WRT device?

Comment: Your approach, having a webserver elsewhere would work also. But I think I was not clear enough before what I really want to do:  If I connect to any router in a network entering its IP Adresse .e.g. 192.168.1.1, I end up in "web page", where i can change user settings, display certain router statistics, etc.
If I click a button on these pages there must be internal variables changed, databases manipulated, scripts executed, etc. My goal is to setup a simular page. Do you know how these "web pages" are set up? I mean what develop enviroment are used? Sorry for the dumb question..

Comment: Thats now multiple different questions - What do routers use to implement control via a web ui? (too broad) Is the approach they take viable for your circumstances? (too broad) What's the security track record for such devices? (poor) Is predicating the design of such a system on a mysql database a good idea? (probably not / too broad)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a database for that.
Look at OpenWrt documentation and you will find that most configs reside inside `/etc/config` which consists of files with specific formats that you use to control a specific part of the router.
Also for firewall related things you could use a config file that resides inside `/etc/` and read by the `fw3` package.
I suggest you take a look at the documentation and join the irc channel and ask specific questions there.